# I need a 2D bone engine for JavaScript

Tags: 2d, javascript

I'm looking for a way to define a Bone animation system, I need a basic one, since my objective is to apply it for inverse kinematics, much like Flash supports.

The desirable feature is that: I can set bones (as position in 2D, defined by 2 dots) each having an ID. So I can make an animation based on *frames*, ie:

```
['l_leg', [10, 0],[ 13,30 ] ] ['r_leg', [30, 0 ], [13, 30] ] //Frame 1 (standing)
['l_leg', [10, 0],[ 13,30 ] ] ['r_leg', [35, 30], [13, 30] ] //Frame 2 (lifting right leg)
...
```

I'm confident that defining *Joints* ain't necessary.

The lib may be lib in Ruby, since I can port it to JS, but if in JS already is better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: deprecated** for a long time now.

I am developing my own: http://github.com/flockonus/javascriptinmotion

Answer (score 0):

See [Wikipedia: Express Animator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Express_Animator).

1st result for Google: *javascript skeletal*.